# Error for UniqueConstraint with custom type in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a test that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class TestTruckRepository {
    @Autowired
    private TruckRepository truckRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void doIt(){
        //omitted
    }
}
```

The method doIt() isn't even reached. The error I am receiving is:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (PlateNumber) on table Truck: database column 'plateNumber' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
```

Here is the class that the error is refering to:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"plateNumber"}))
public class Truck implements Identifiable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private PlateNumber plateNumber;
    private String stuff;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

 //Getter setter and constructor are omitted.
}
```

If I remove the 'uniqueConstraints = ....' then it seems to be working fine, but the property is not unique. Any ideas om how to solve this? The error is telling me to look at the naming. I would really like to avoid putting @Column or @JoinColumn(I know this otherwise solves it) on all of my properties. I am guessing that hibernate is creating a name that is different from the property since it is more complex than just having a String as a property, but I would like to avoid having that information stored inside my classes.

EDIT: All tables are created by hibernate so I cannot go into a database and just look up the column name.

Comment: You decided you want a particular column as unique, yet don't define the @Column for the field that will be this column. A N-1 will be a FK and will have a particular name as default ... and it will NOT be "plateNumber"

Comment: Defining @ Column isn't even practically possible as far as I know, I think the option I would have is @ JoinColumn and this forces me to specify strings as column names. I would prefer hibernate generating these.

Comment: Well being pedantic the annotation is JoinColumn but the point is the same. You are NOT defining the auto-generated name so it will be generated for you and this auto-generated name will NOT be "plateNumber" yet you expect there to be a column called "plateNumber". And there isn't. So it all falls apart. So define it. And you defined a String as a column name for the Unique, so don't understand the reticence

Answer (score 0):

what is the column name for plateNumber in truck table (check in DB)?

```
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"plateNumber"})
```

UniqueConstraint has columnNames so it doesn't have to be the same as your property name. What naming strategy do you use ? JPA creates tables, columns and other object's name according to configured naming strategy. By default SimpleNamingStrategy should be used and in that case it should work, because resulted column name should be property name plateNumber.

Comment: This db is for a small and simple application(at least for now) so I am l just letting jpa/hibernate create the tables. I have not defined a naming strategy, so in my mind the default name should be plateNumber.

Comment: Try to check if column name is correct in DB ... If you want to explicitly define column name use @JoinColumn

Comment: if you dont want to use JoinColumn, than change columnName in your UniqueConstraint annotation to generated value from hibernate.